# htaccess location rewrite resource loading fails

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to do:

- Making my shop script SEO friendly
- Using htaccess to turn something like `/product.php?id=12345` into `/product/awesome-product-name`

What I already achieved:

- Link redirection `/product/awesome-product-name` is now a working link

My problem is that I cant load any resources because of the subdir `products`. What I need is an easy way to change the paths to images, css and javascript files.

Current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^produkt/(.*)$ ./product.php?url=$1
RewriteRule 404 404.html
```

I dont think my question is a duplicate cause my shop files are in a sub-directory of the main webserver. So I cant access my css and js files just by putting a `/` in the href, like it was the answer in one of the given `duplicates`.

## FIXED

My solution is adding the RewriteRule `RewriteRule ^produkte/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /shop/$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]` to my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: And how does your current .htaccess file look like?

Comment: @OlafDietsche added my current .htaccess